# Is it possible to set the sitemap option programmatically using the module Simple XML Sitemap?

Tags: 8, xml-sitemap

On my drupal instance I have enabled the module called Simple XML Sitemap. The problem now is I want to toggle the option to index certain pages programmatically. I can't find out how. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are API methods to alter stored inclusion settings and generate the sitemap programmatically. There is <del>no documentation other than</del> the [documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/simple-xml-sitemap) and [code documentation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/simple_sitemap/tree/src/Simplesitemap.php) which is pretty complete. Here are the service methods which can be used to accomplish what you need:

```
getSetting()
saveSetting()
getSitemap()
generateSitemap()
getGeneratedAgo()
enableEntityType()
disableEntityType()
setBundleSettings()
getBundleSettings()
setEntityInstanceSettings()
getEntityInstanceSettings()
removeEntityInstanceSettings()
bundleIsIndexed()
entityTypeIsEnabled()
addCustomLink()
getCustomLinks()
getCustomLink()
removeCustomLink()
removeCustomLinks()
```

You can chain these methods like so:

```
\Drupal::service('simple_sitemap.generator')
  ->saveSetting('remove_duplicates', TRUE)
  ->enableEntityType('node')
  ->setBundleSettings('node', 'page', ['index' => TRUE, 'priority' = 0.5])
  ->removeCustomLinks()
  ->addCustomLink('/some/view/page', ['priority' = 0.5])
  ->generateSitemap();
```

I have just added the above information to the [documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/simple-xml-sitemap), we would appreciate anyone further contributing to it.